# Find matching elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this {A1,B5,C6,A2,B7,C4};
I want to loop through the array and find the matching element and then do some manipulation in that match. 
The match in the above array is A1 and A2, B5 and B7 and finally C6 and C4.

Below is what I have done so far:

```
var arr = {A1,B5,C6,A2,B7,C4};
for (i=0; i < arr.length/2; i++) // Only running till length/2 since there is always another match hence don't need to run through all the length probably
{
for (j=i+1; j < arr.length; j++)
       {
         if(arr[i].charAt(0) == arr[j].charAt(0))
           {
             j=arr.length; //This is done to end the inner loop
             Do something;
             //if the matching element is found, ideally the i loop should ignore this record. I don't know how to do this.
           }
       }
 }
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I'm guessing javascript, but OP needs to tag appropriately.

Comment: sorry, doing this. I would say its language agnostic but I'm not a dev so I'll put it there

Comment: Comments use `//`, not `\\ `. Your `arr` is not valid, nor an array.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort the array first to make it easier to find the matching pairs. Here is one way you can modify your code.

```js
var arr = ['A1','B5','C6','A2','B7','C4']

arr.sort();
console.log("Sorted array : " + arr);
for (i=0; i < arr.length -1; i++) // Only running till length/2 since there is always another match hence don't need to run through all the length probably
{
         if(arr[i].charAt(0) == arr[i+1].charAt(0))
           {
             j=arr.length; //This is done to end the inner loop
              console.log("Match found : " + arr[i].charAt(0));
             //if the matching element is found, ideally the i loop should ignore this record. I don't know how to do this.
           }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush! Any other way where I don't have to sort the array?

Comment: I disagree that sorting *saves* unnecessary code and complexion, and would argue it's actually the complete opposite. Sorting is an extra step, and *adds* processing time. You can loop through the array and separate the matches based on the first character, instead of sorting and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object with all the matches, like so:

```js
var arr = ['A1','B5','C6','A2','B7','C4'];
var setsOfMatches = {};
arr.forEach(function(currentItem) {
    var firstLetter = [currentItem.charAt(0)];
    if (setsOfMatches[firstLetter]) {                 //If we have a set for this letter already
        setsOfMatches[firstLetter].push(currentItem); //Add this item to it
    } else {                                          
     setsOfMatches[firstLetter] = [currentItem];   //Create the set
    }
});

//console.log(setsOfMatches);
//{  
//   A:["A1","A2"],
//   B:["B5","B7"],
//   C:["C6","C4"]
//}

//Iterate through the sets of matches
for (var set in setsOfMatches) {
    console.log("Set " + set + ": " + setsOfMatches[set]);
}
```